# Display iAds on Splash Screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iad, splash-screen

Is it possible to put iAd on splash screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean the Default.png splash screen? if so no.
But if you have created your own splash screen then it's possible just like you'd normally ad an iAd.